# Control top padding of H1 element in relation to bottom of above P element

Tags: html, css

In a basic block of html the top padding of the H1 element appears to be in relation to the H1 element above it and not the P element right above it. 
Since I have a varying amount of P elements I can't use their bottom padding to control the position of the H1 element below, without affecting the spacing between each P element.

How do I get the H1 element to pad relative to the P above it?

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>text text</p>
<p>text text</p>
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>text text</p>
<p>text text</p>
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>text text</p>
<p>text text</p>
```

Here is my CSS, which seems would create 27px between the bottom of the P element and the top of the H1 element.

```
p {
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 15px;
padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
}

h1 {

font-size: 22px;
line-height: 22px;
font-weight: 200;
padding: 15px 0px 20px 0px;
margin: 0
}
```

Currently there is 12px of padding from the bottom of the P element to the top of the H1, and increasing the padding on the top of the H1 element does not increase the space between the P and the H1, but it does increase the space between the top of the H1 and the bottom of the H1 above it.

It is as if the H1 element ignores the properties of the P element and only reacts to the H1 above it.

Comment: Hard to understand your situation from your description.  Could you post the CSS for your h1 and p elements along with a specific description of what you expect to be rendered?  (For example, "I expect therefore 30px between the top of the h1 and the bottom of its sibling p.")

Comment: Those specifics help.  What amount are you measuring?

Comment: there is a default margin set on `p` elements. unless you have reset it elsewhere that is also going to be in effect.

Comment: I made further updates to help clarify more.

Comment: Why are you floating your paragraphs but not your headers?

Comment: @Eric, would that be what is affecting this?

Comment: @sterling: Almost certainly. What are you trying to achieve by floating your paragraphs?

Comment: @Eric, that was the solution, removing the float got everything to work as expected. Thank you so much for pointing that out, I honestly forgot it was there and had no specific reason for using it. I must have cut and paste the block of code. If you post an answer I will most happily select it as you solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you floating your paragraphs but not your headers?

Margins behave differently when applied to floats, particularly in IE7 and below. Unless you have any real reason to float the paragraphs, don't!

Answer (score 3):

you could try:

`p + h1 {padding: 0 0;}`

obviously substituting your padding values. [But really its the `margin` collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) that is changing the spacing, not the padding.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PBJwm/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, padding is never a matter of being "relative" to anything else.  Padding refers to the interior "spacing" of the element.

CSS troubleshooting tip:  For margin, padding or positioning situations like this, I often find it helpful to specify background colors for each element in question.  So if you gave your H1 a red background and your p a blue background, your expectation will only hold true if there is no gap between your red H1's and your blue p's.  Use background instead of border since border changes overall dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but it seems by increasing the interior spacing of one element would increase the distance from the element above it. Is this not accurate?

Comment: @sterling @Larsenal errr, sorry to jump in here so late, but that's not really the net result.  Think of the objects as cars driven by you and someone else.  The margin on the cars is 0.  They are in contact with each other and causing a lot of expensive damage.  If you increase the padding, all you are doing is moving yourself (your body) to the other side of the car.  The cars are still in contact.  If you actually want space between objects, use margins.

Comment: Yes, @rockerest, I understand.  Margins may very well be what he wants, but from the OP's perspective he noticed a difference in spacing between the people... not the cars.  My suggestion in the comment above should help him to see the cars, and help him understand everything involved here.